# How to push array object to previous array in javascript { node js }

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Here is I am getting issue on traversing array. but not getting proper result.
first for loop is traversing and in it another loop is traversing.

```
    var f_array = s_array = {};

    for ( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {

        var v_c = '1500';

        for ( var j = 0; j < 20 ; j++) {

            s_array[j] = 'abc';
        }       

        f_array = { 'v_c' : v_c,  'years' : s_array };  
    }

console.log(f_array);     // showing only last array object that is i = 9 , I want it all of them.
```

Here I am updating my question with required result should be like below array.

```
{
  "v_c": "1500",
    "years": {
      "0": "asd",
      "1": "asd",
     .
     .
     .
      "9": "asd"
    }
},
{
  "v_c": "1500",
    "years": {
      "0": "asd",
      "1": "asd",
     .
     .
     .
      "9": "asd"
    }
},
{
  "v_c": "1500",
    "years": {
      "0": "asd",
      "1": "asd",
     .
     .
     .
      "9": "asd"
    }
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: `{}` is an object, not an array...

Comment: after changing this. my problem remain same.

Comment: what is the proper result?

Answer (score 2):

Your final code should be like this

```
var f_array = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {

    var v_c = '1500',
        s_array = [];

    for ( var j = 0; j < 9 ; j++) {
        s_array.push('abc');
    }       

    f_array.push( { 'v_c' : v_c,  'years' : s_array });  
}
```

It will create a new array(`s_array`) for every `f_array`entry, so you will have no problem.
`f_array`should be an array of objects as you showed.